# Thread for each iframe on the page

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I develop an application which uses tabs, every tab has an `iframe` which loads content while the application is running (this does not happen when the application loads).

Since the contents of the `iframes` are very big and really need performance, my application is blocked for a couple seconds.

My question: is it possible to let every iframe on the page execute in its own Thread?

Comment: No, there is no such way - this is considered implementation detail. A [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99379) is assigned on chromium. Currently it will all run in the same frame.

Comment: Okay, bad to hear, but thank you anyway :)

Comment: Sorry for the negative answer, there might be a way to do it in node-webkit that I'm not aware of so don't lose hope.

Comment: have you looked at using Web Workers ?  each runs in its own independent thread - and transferring **HUGE** Transferable Object flavor of typed array's to/from any WW and browser is surprisingly snappy ... dunno how performant node-webkit is in keeping up with this browser technology however its already on all top shelf laptop browsers as well as thier lillipop android brothers

Answer (score 0):

You can give `<webview>` a try since webview runs in separate process.
[webview nwjs](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nwjs-general/qWJczc-E92E/9lmIiMfysU8J) introduced in nwjs alpha release.

webviews are very restricted and you have no access to the document loaded inside webview directly from parent. Communication can be done using postMessage api

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview